# Distance between 2 locations method

Tags: java, class, math

For this code, I am trying to determine the distance between (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). The equation for the distance is sqrt(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2.

The code looks like this,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoordinateGeometry {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  double x1;
  double y1;
  double x2;
  double y2;
  double pointsDistance;
  double xDist;
  double yDist;

  pointsDistance = 0.0;
  xDist = 0.0;
  yDist = 0.0;

  x1 = scnr.nextDouble();
  y1 = scnr.nextDouble();
  x2 = scnr.nextDouble();
  y2 = scnr.nextDouble();

  poinsDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + (Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));

  System.out.println(pointsDistance);
  }
}
```

I keep getting an error, CoordinateGeometry.java:23: error: ')' expected
      poinsDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + (Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
                                                                             ^
1 error

What does this error mean?

Also an example would be, for points (1.0, 2.0) and (1.0, 5.0), pointsDistance is 3.0.

Comment: didn't close properly the instruction. Need one `)`

Comment: (Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2). remove ( before Math.pow

Comment: Got it to work turns out I had the pointsDistance as poinsDistance and an extra ")".

Comment: Squaring numbers using Math.pow is inefficient.  A better way is to multiple the value by itself: x_squared = x*x;

Answer (score 2):

You are missing closing `)` at the end of line

`poinsDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + (Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)));`

Or remove the opening `(` before `Math.pow`.

Your code should look like this:

`poinsDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));`

Comment: I just tried that but got this error instead, CoordinateGeometry.java:23: error: ')' expected
      poinsDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + (Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
                                                                                                                         ^1 error

Comment: @StevenVillarreal note that he has `)))` at the end whereas you still have `))`.